# Share services between multiple boostrapped component

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I created 2 components which are boostrapped separately (in 2 different views), and I try to share a unique service (singleton) between these 2 components. The service is use to manipulate one of these component. My service :

```ts
@Injectable()
export class ModalContainerService {
    private component: ModalContainer;

    constructor() {}

    setComponent(component: ModalContainer) {
        this.component = component; <-- for holding the reference to my component
    }

    showFirst() {
        this.component.showFirst();
    }

    addModal(modal: Type) {
        this.component.addModal(modal);
    }
}
```

The first component :

```ts
export class ModalContainer {
    private modals: Array<ComponentRef> = [];

    constructor(
        private loader: DynamicComponentLoader,
        private element: ElementRef,
        private modalService: ModalContainerService) {
        modalService.setComponent(this); <-- where I set the component reference for my service
    }

    showFirst(): void {
        this.modals[0].instance.show();
    }

    addModal(modal: Type) {
        this.loader
            .loadIntoLocation(modal, this.element, 'modalContainer')
            .then((ref) => {
                this.modals.push(ref);
            });
    }
}

bootstrap(ModalContainer, [ModalContainerService]);
```

And my second component, which is boostrapped apart of the first component :

```ts
export class TextboxAutocomplete {    
    constructor(private modelService: ModalContainerService) {}
}
```

But the ModalContainerService doesn't contains the reference of my first component anymore ...
Is it possible to share datas / services between 2 components boostrapped separately ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't get what service you want to share therefore I use `FooService` as name.

Create an instance of `FooService` outside Angular then pass the value as provider to booth `bootstrap()`

```
var fooService = new FooService();
bootstrap(AppComponent1, [provide(FooService, {useValue: fooService})]);
bootstrap(AppComponent2, [provide(FooService, {useValue: fooService})]);
```