# What exactly does the provide function get as parameters?

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, angular

I'm reading an [article](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html) about angular 2 DI and having hard time to understand what does the provide function get as parameters.

> We have a function provide() that maps a token to a configuration
>   object. The token can either be a type or a string. We provide an
>   instance of type Car via the class Car.

```
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';

var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
  provide(Car, {useClass: Car})
]);
```

**My questions are:**

1. What is a token and what it's job?
2. What is the difference between instance of type and a Class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without `provide` a provider is just a type, if requested an instance of this type is injected.

Provide allows to map the requested type or another kind of token (string, OpaqueToken) to map to another type or to a concrete value.

The first parameter is therefore the type or token.

- useClass `provide(XHRBackend, {useClass: MockBackend}`
  If a constructor requests `XHRBackend` (like `Http` does) pass in an instance of `MockBackend`
- useExisting `provide(XHRBackend, {useExisting: MockBackend}`
  If a constructor requests `XHRBackend` request a `MockBackend` instance from DI and pass it.
- useValue `provide(XHRBackend, {useValue: someMockBackendReference}`
  If a constructor requests `XHRBackend` pass in an the value referred to by `someMockBackendReference`. This is convenient for passing configuration values to consumers.
  See [Share services between multiple boostrapped component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35607976/share-services-between-multiple-boostrapped-component) for an example.
- useFactory allows DI to provide a class instance, DI can't create on its own. For example if a class has constructor parameters, but it is not annotated with `@Injectable()` or the parameter doesn't have a type and you can't add it yourself because the class is from a library maintained by someone else.

```
provide(XHRBackend, {
    useFactory: (options:BaseRequestOptions) => {
        return new BaseRequestOptions(5);
    },
    deps: [ObservableDataService]
});
```

For more information about DI see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html

**Update**

1) What is a token and what it's job?

A token is a string or `OpaqueToken` that allows to identify a value that doesn't have a distinct type. This allows you to provide and inject different kinds of strings and numbers for example which can't be distinguished by the type.

2) What is the difference between instance of type and a Class?

The instance of a class is a value that you get at runtime when you execute `new SomeClass()`. Its a value built from a class where the class is the template for the layout of the value and the constructor is executed to initialize the value.

The type of a value is the reference to the class it was built from.

Comment: Thanks for the information. You explained what provider is but you did not answer any of my questions.

Comment: Right missed that. The title of your questions asks what `provide` function does get as parameters.

Comment: Maybe I should be more specific. What is the difference between  instance of type Car and class Car In the example above?

Comment: "instance of type Car" is a value in a running application that represents a car (actually a real car) according to the `Car` class you wrote in your source code. The `Car` class is just in the source code you wrote (the blueprint of a car). The `Car` type is a reference from the `Car` value to the `Car` class (a marker on the car according to which blueprint is was built).

Comment: Simply put class/type Car is `{name: undefined, color: undefined}`, instance is `{name: "BMW", color: "Red"}`...